# Simple Javascript/NodeJS issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, javascript-objects

i have created a require module and i when 'required' the constructor should automatically take in any parameter value instantiate all the variables and functions and return that object to the file that called the required module. i might not be explaining it correct, so here is an example:

```
var test = require('./testFramework'); //this works fine
var socketIo = new require('./socketIoTests')(test); //<<this does not work
```

at the end of this, socketIo remains undefined.

the module.exports on the socketIoTest.js file is simplified to:

```
var socketIo = function(testFramework){
    var test = testFramework
    this.someArray = [...];

    this.testSockets = function(){...}
}

module.exports = socketIo;
```

now as you can imagine because i am creating an object it is possible to do the following and it works exactly i expect:

```
var test = require('./testFramework');
var socketIo = require('./socketIoTests');

var newObj = new socketIo(test); //<<this works
```

here the variable newObj, returns with the object and public properties i expect, but is there a way to cut this step out with something like:

```
var socketIo = new require('./socketIoTests')(test);
```

i suspect this is either really straight forward and i need to learn javascript better or this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var socketIo = new (require('./socketIoTests'))(test);
```

should work just fine.

Your socketIo function is not a constructor. It is simply a function. For it to function as a constructor, you need to use `new`. If you want to avoid using `new`, you can simply create an object in the function, attach all properties to that object instead of `this` and return the object.

```
var socketIo = function(testFramework){
    var test = testFramework;
    var socketIoObject = {};
    socketIoObject.someArray = [...];

    socketIoObject.testSockets = function(){...}

    return socketIoObject;
}

module.exports = socketIo;
```

Comment: thanks! im going to opt for the top solution so i can works on the object as if it were a regular JS object without having to create additional variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your module.exports become a function so you can do the `require('./socketIoTests')(test);` kind of thing.

Make your module as follow

```
module.exports = function (theParam) {

    // Do something with the param ...
    // var yourDesiredValue = ...

    return yourDesiredValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks. this certainly works but there are more functions+variables to be added that need to be public/private, so i am going to go for the solution: var socketIo = new (require('./socketIoTests'))(test); so i can manage it as a regular JS object without having the overhead of dealing with the variables. you solution is great but not quite necessary for my solution.